# Verification of user and admin not working properly in following code:

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, verification

In verifyAdmin function the verifyToken is passed where with the help of jwt the user property is added to the request and then using that property's key isAdmin we can check if the user is admin or not but in the below given code it is not working. Also same issue is being faced for the verifyUser.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { createError } from "../utils/error.js";

// This verifies that is the token correct i.e. weather person is admin or not
export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) {
    return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return next(createError(403, "Token is not valid!"));
    //  Here in place of the req.user you can write any property as nothing is defined in request
    req.user = user;
    console.log(req.user);
    next();
  });
};

// To verify the user
export const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
  // If the user have the token i.e. user needs to be authenticated.
  verifyToken(req, res, next, () => {
    // If the user id matches or user is admin then CRUD operations can be performed.
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
      next();
    } else {
      return next(createError(403, "You are not authorized!"));
    }
  });
};

export const verifyAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, next, () => {
    console.log(`Before or After Token`);
    if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
      next();
    } else {
      return next(createError(403, "You are not authorized!"));
    }
  });
};
```

Here the user details are perfectly verified till verifyToken when passed from verifyAdmin but then it is not checking for the admin or user in verifUser function.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same error. Just exactly as you mentioned it
This code will solve your problem.

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    //your code here
    next();
}
const verifyUser= (req, res, next) => {
    //your code here
    next();
}
router.post("/user/:id", verifyToken, verifyUser, (req, res) => {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { createError } from "../utils/error.js";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return next(createError(403, "Token is not valid!"));
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};

export const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, () => { // Remove the `next` parameter from `verifyToken` call
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.role === "admin") {
      next();
    } else {
      return next(createError(403, "You are not authorized!"));
    }
  });
};

export const verifyAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, () => { // Remove the `next` parameter from `verifyToken` call
    console.log("ishlepti");
    console.log(req.user);

    if (req.user.role === "admin") {
      next();
    } else {
      return next(createError(403, "You are not authorized as Admin!"));
    }
  });
};
```

By removing the next parameter from the verifyToken calls in **verifyUser** and **verifyAdmin** functions, the code should work as expected. However, please note that this assumes the rest of your code, including the **createError** function and the usage of the **req.cookies.access_token** and **process.env.JWT**, is correct.

If you encounter any specific error messages or further issues, please provide that information for further assistance.